# R - how can I dump contents of file to console output?

Tags: r

I simply want to read a file and output it in the console.  print( readLines(...) ) is the best I can do so far, but I don't want a line-by-line identifier, I just want the file as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but `?cat` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: this seems to work:  cat( readLines( FILEPATH ) , sep = "\n" )  although a bit awkward that I'm reading a file line by line just to write it out with a new line separator.  Perhaps there's a function to just read an entire file to a string without any delimiters or any parsing at all - just "as-is"?

Comment: This is a terrible answer as it has nothing to do with the content of a file. In particular calling cat(file=<your filename>) will delete the content of your file because the file argument is an output override to cat.

Answer (score 16):

Use `writeLines` instead of `print`. The default `con` for `writeLines` is `stdout()`, so `writeLines(readLines(...))` sounds right.

See `?writeLines`.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get (say) the first 50 lines?

Comment: n=50 https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html

Answer (score 6):

You could use `system` to call a system command.

```
system("cat yourfile.txt")
```

Comment: OT: get Rtools, you'll never look back

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify a length (which can be too big), but maybe `readChar` would help:

```
cat(readChar(filename, 1e5))
```

Comment: good idea.  I'll stick to readlines since it guarantees that all lines will be read

Comment: can't you combine both options in one answer?

Comment: I could, but I thought different answers were supposed to be in, well, different answers.  I looked for this in the FAQ but didn't find it, so I'm not sure where I saw that, if anywhere.  What's recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elegant way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
readLines("init.R") %>% paste0(collapse="\n") %>% cat
```

or with base R

```
cat(paste0(readLines("init.R"), collapse="\n"))
```

remember to replace `init.R` with the file path `myfolder/myfile.R`

Comment: There is nothing `dplyr` specific in this solution, you're just using the `magrittr` pipe (https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/). Since R 4.0.5 you can also use the base R pipe `|>`